# How to pass authentication/authorization from postman for web api developed in GoogleAppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, postman

I have developed small web API to get/ post data in googleappscript editor (https://script.google.com). In the deployment model for "Who has access" I've chosen "Only Myself". While I'm testing the API using postman it failed due to Authorization

What kind of authentication do I need to use? How to add authentication in postman for googleappscript API?

I tried with my google account but no luck